# How does lattice reduction algorithm reduce condition number of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, condition-number

I've read from a book that "An ill-conditioned matrix can be transformed to a well-conditioned one through [Lattice reduction algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction)."

The ill-conditioned matrix means that the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) is large, while the well-conditioned matrix refers to a small condition number.

I've browsed through the internet, but I did not find any information on this.

I would like to ask if this is true?

If this is true, how can it be done?

---

More formally, given an ill-conditioned square matrix $A\in{\mathbf{C}^{N\times{N}}}$, is it possible to find a lattice reduction matrix $P$ such that $AP$ is well-conditioned? How can we find the matrix $P$?

---

I would like to know this property since I have got a bunch of ill-conditioned matrices and intend to solve the linear system by some convex optimization techniques after the lattice transform (ex. Jacobi-Method, Coordinate descent, ...).

Comment: what book?  what lattice are they reducing?

Comment: @WillJagy 8.3.5 of the book "Baseband Receiver Design for Wireless MIMO-OFDM Communications (2nd. edition)." (https://imgur.com/B0mZRIL)

Comment: The answer to your question will be very specific to that particular application.

Comment: You are going to need to tell us either of two things: (I) the Gram matrix for your lattice or (II) a matrix, posssibly rectangular, with either the rows or the columns a basis for your lattice

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, I've got it! So the lattice reduction matrix depends on the lattice basis I define, but not the given matrix $A$. I can easily find a matrix $P$, not related to the lattice, to transform the matrix into a well-conditioned one.